# Сhanging the privacy of methods due to tests

Tags: java, testing

The project uses SonarQube. If your MR (PR) test coverage is below a certain percentage, then your MR (PR) does not pass.
It is often necessary to write a test for a private method. Private methods are difficult to test. There was an agreement in the team: if you need to write a test for a private method, you can make this method package-private or default.
I know that it's OK to change the code for tests. But I'm worried about a question. Won't such an uncontrolled change in the modifier of methods for the sake of tests lead to architectural problems after a year or two or three ...?

Comment: Testing private methods is arguably a code smell. Tests should generally be written against public contracts. But if you need to expose a method for testing, you can annotate it with [`@VisibleForTesting`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) or the like as a warning to developers.

Comment: Private methods are normally tested through the tests for the public API. Proactively testing private method is often a sign, that it should be a separate class, refactor accordingly. Changing visibility for tests breaks the encapsulation, the next person who works on the code, may not be aware that it was increased for tests only and use the incorrect methods at the incorrect place.